# How can I access a class array from another class

Tags: c#, arrays, class

```
public partial class FormRestaurant : Form
     public Tables[] AllTables = new Tables[4];
```

I create an array of type `Tables` which is a class that I made. If I try to reference this from a third class (`Parties.cs`) by doing:

```
public void AssignTable()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < **FormRestaurant.AllTables**.Length; i++)
        {
            if (**FormRestaurant.AllTables[i]**.TableCapacity <= PartySize)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I am told that I need an object reference. How exactly do I do this?

I tried making the array static but it didn't seem to work. Also I get this error when I try to make the `AllTables` array public.

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type
>   'Restaurant_Spil.Tables[]' is less accessible than field
>   'Restaurant_Spil.FormRestaurant.AllTables'

Comment: Make sure your `Tables` class is also publicly accessible.

Comment: is the `Tables` Class public ?

Comment: Can you show the actual code that is giving you these errors?

Comment: What is `Restaurant_Spil.Tables[]`? your instance variable?

Comment: Restaurant_Spil.Tables[] is my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it says you need an object reference, it's trying to tell you that it needs an instance of your class. Say you have your class:

```
public partial class FormRestaurant : Form
{
     public Tables[] AllTables = new Tables[4];
}
```

If you want to get the length of the Tables[] array in Parties.cs, then Parties needs an *instance* of FormRestaurant; it makes no sense to ask for the length of FormRestaurant.AllTables. Instead you should:

```
public class Parties
{
    int length;
    FormRestaurant f;
    public Parties()
    {
        f = new FormRestaurant();
        length = f.AllTables.Length;
    }
}
```

the `f` variable is the `object reference` that was mentioned in your first error.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is put your `Tables` class public.
You cannot expose `private` field type in a `public` class

Comment: So in order to make an array of type Tables public, the class must be public?